# How to do Rdd and broadcasted Rdd multiplication in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two data frames like Below:

data frame1:(df1)

```
+---+----------+
|id |features  |
+---+----------+
|8  |[5, 4, 5] |
|9  |[4, 5, 2] |
+---+----------+
```

data frame2:(df2)

```
+---+----------+
|id |features  |
+---+----------+
|1  |[1, 2, 3] |
|2  |[4, 5, 6] |
+---+----------+
```

after that i have converted into Df to Rdd

```
rdd1=df1.rdd
```

if I am doing `rdd1.collect()` result is like below

```
[Row(id=8, f=[5, 4, 5]), Row(id=9, f=[4, 5, 2])]

rdd2=df2.rdd

broadcastedrddif = sc.broadcast(rdd2.collectAsMap())
```

now if I am doing broadcastedrddif.value

```
{1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [4, 5, 6]}
```

now i want to do sum of multiplication of rdd1 and broadcastedrddif i.e it should return output like below.

```
((8,[(1,(5*1+2*4+5*3)),(2,(5*4+4*5+5*6))]),(9,[(1,(4*1+5*2+2*3)),(2,(4*4+5*5+2*6)]) ))
```

so my final output should be

```
((8,[(1,28),(2,70)]),(9,[(1,20),(2,53)]))
```

where (1, 28) is a tuple not a float.

Please help me on this.

Comment: where do ids 8 and 9 come from? in line `[Row(id=8, f=[5, 4, 5]), Row(id=9, f=[4, 5, 2])]` they are the key of your PairRDD in your expected output

Comment: thanks for reply...ya,I got the 8,9 from one of  the from my Ml algo.yes in my final output they are the keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand why you used `sc.broadcast()` but i used it anyway...
Very useful in this case mapValues on the last RDD and I used a list comprehension to execute the operations using the dictionary.

```
x1=sc.parallelize([[8,5,4,5], [9,4,5,2]]).map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1],x[2],x[3])))
x1.collect()
x2=sc.parallelize([[1,1,2,3], [2,4,5,6]]).map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1],x[2],x[3])))
x2.collect()
#I took immediately an RDD because is more simply to test
broadcastedrddif = sc.broadcast(x2.collectAsMap())
d2=broadcastedrddif.value

def sum_prod(x,y):
    c=0
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        c+=x[i]*y[i]
    return c
x1.mapValues(lambda x: [(i, sum_prod(list(x),list(d2[i]))) for i in [k for k in d2.keys()]]).collect()
Out[19]: [(8, [(1, 28), (2, 70)]), (9, [(1, 20), (2, 53)])]
```

Comment: Hi Carlov,Thanks For quick reply its working as expected.